# find top n% and then find averages of the top n% per groupid in R

Tags: r

Pardon my English. I've tried doing this in SQL but to no avail. Is this possible in R?

I'm trying to:

Find the Top 10% of scores per groupid then find the average of scores for those 10% by groupid

Sample data:

Table name: points

`groupid       score
group_001     13
group_001     12
group_001     10
group_001     12
...
group_002     12
group_002     16
group_002     19
group_002     20
group_002     12
group_002     13
...
group_003     29
group_003     21
group_003     18
...`

...

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `dplyr` package and assuming your data frame is called `dat`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% group_by(groupid) %>% 
   filter(percent_rank(score)>=0.9) %>% 
   summarise(mean_top10pct=mean(score))
```